# It is not displaying data correctly in php/html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have an "Answer" database table below:

Answer Table

```
AnswerId SessionId QuestionId Answer
13       AAA       1          A
14       AAC       1          True
```

Now as you can see there is 1 answer for question 1 in Exam (Session) AAA, and these is 1 answer for question 1 in Exam (Session) AAC.

Below is the "Question" Table:

Question Table:

```
SessionId  QuestionId QuestionContent NoofAnswers ReplyId QuestionMarks OptionId
AAA        1          What is 2+2?    1           1       5             2
AAC        1          Is 3+3 = 6?     1           1       5             25
```

Now I have a search function where the user enters in a term from a question and compiles the search. So for example if the user enters in "2+2", then below is what the results should display in the php/html table:

```
   QuestionContent Option Type  Number of Answers Answer Number of Replies  Number of Marks
   What is 2+2?    A-D          1                 A      Single             5
```

But the problem is that it is displaying an extra row, it is displaying this below:

```
   QuestionContent Option Type  Number of Answers Answer Number of Replies  Number of Marks
   What is 2+2?    A-D          1                 A True    Single             5
   What is 2+2?    A-D          1                 A True    Single             5
```

Now what my question is that why is it displaying two rows and why is it including the answer "True" under the "Answer" column when the answer for that question should just be "A"? I believe it is because both questions have the same QuestionId (Question number) but they both belong to different SessionId's so this should not be a problem.

Below is the code (Which I have reduced so it is easier for you to read and hopefully see the problem) where it performs the query and outputs the results:

```
<?php

//connect to db


    // Build the query
    $questionquery = "
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
       q.QuestionMarks 
  FROM Answer an 
  INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
  JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
  JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
      WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
      GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
      ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
    ";

    // Make the referenced array
    $referencedArray = make_values_referenced(array_merge(
      array(str_repeat("ss", $numTerms)), // types
      $termArray,                         // where
      $termArray                          // order by
    ));


    // Bind parameters
    if (!call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), make_values_referenced($referencedArray))) {
      die("Error binding parameters: $stmt->error"); 
    }


    // This will hold the search results
    $searchResults = array();
    $searchOption = array();
    $searchNoofAnswers = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchReply = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array
    if (!$stmt->num_rows()) {
      $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionContent,$dbOptionType,$dbNoofAnswers,$dbAnswer,$dbReplyType,$dbQuestionMarks); 
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchResults[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchOption[] = $dbOptionType;
        $searchNoofAnswers[] = $dbNoofAnswers;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchReply[] = $dbReplyType;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      }
    }

  }


      $questionnum = sizeof($searchResults);

    // If $searchResults is not empty we got results
    if (!empty($searchResults)) {
      echo "<p>Your Search: '$inputValue'</p>";  
      echo"<p>Number of Questions Shown from the Search: <strong>$questionnum</strong></p>";
      echo "<table border='1' id='resulttbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='optiontypeth'>Option Type</th>
      <th class='noofanswersth'>Number of <br/> Answers</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='noofrepliesth'>Number of <br/> Replies</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Number of <br/> Marks</th>
      </tr>\n";
      $script = '';
      foreach ($searchResults as $key=>$question) {
      $script .= 'var key_' . $key . '="' . str_replace('"','\"', $question) . '";' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="noofanswerstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars(implode(' ', $searchAnswer)).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<td class="noofrepliestd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchReply[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow(key_$key,'$searchMarks[$key]','$searchNoofAnswers[$key]','$searchOption[$key]','$searchReply[$key]','$searchAnswer[$key]');\">Add</button></td></tr>";
}
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo $script;
        echo '</script>' . PHP_EOL;


}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry reply late, my answer updated as well, please check and let me know if it solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems about your db schema you defined is not the way you use it, I mean it seems the unique value on the Answer Table should be answerID or SessionId+QuestionId, so if you use that table in a query you should also include SessionId in your join condition with Question table, I mean here at least it looks two different questions in different session can have same questionID is the key problem.

So your code should something like following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT     Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
       q.QuestionMarks, q.SessionId
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId and an.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
    WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
    GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
    ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
";
```

The SQL query above **UPDATED** to reflect to the updated question

The new problem still related with the same thing which is the query did not specify session so different question across session might be mixed together, I suggest you query out the sessionID in your select list for grabbing correct data, and hide it on the page if you don't want show it, however keep in mind you need to record that if you have some other detail page to show the question you still need to pass sessionID and QuestionId altogether to that page for identify the unique data

Comment: This has fixed a problem but it then causes a different problem. I will update my question so you know what the other problem is. Give me 5 mins

Comment: Ok I have updated question with new problem I have. I don't think it is anything to do with query. I think its the way I am storing the answers under the "Answer" column in the php/html table but I am not sure

Comment: Sorry reply late, my answer updated as well, please check and let me know if it solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

include `an.QuestionId` in select query.

```
$questionquery = "
SELECT DISTINCT an.QuestionId,q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
   q.QuestionMarks 
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
  WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
  GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
  ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0)  DESC"))."
 ";
```

you have used group by for `an.QuestionId` but not included this in select column, because of this multiple data is coming.

Comment: This has not changed anything. But I have a slightly different problem if you want to have a crack with that one, I updated the question